# PHP - get array if they contain a key=value

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get all array which contain a

```
['tags'] => 'box'
```

Here is my array:

```
array(
    [sale] => Array(
        [url] => ../users
        [label] => Users
        [tags] => box
    )   
    [history] => Array(
        [url] => ../history
        [label] => History
    )   
    [access] => Array(
        [url] => ../history
        [label] => Access
        [tags] => box
    )
)
```

in this array `sale` and `access` have `[tags] => box`, so I want to foreach `sale` and `access`

Comment: And where is your problem?

Comment: I just want to foreach those array which have `[tags] => box`

Comment: Yes, but the Q/A format is done to help you if you are blocking somewhere, not to write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) should work

```
array_filter($array, function($sub) {
  return array_key_exists("tags", $sub) && $sub["tags"] === "box";
});
```

Requires `PHP >= 5.3`

---

Here's a little more of a complete example

```
$filter = function($sub) {
  return array_key_exists("tags", $sub) && $sub["tags"] === "box";
};

foreach (array_filter($array, $filter) as $k => $v) {
  echo $k, " ", $v["url"], "\n";
}
```

Output

```
sale ../users
access ../history
```

---

Alternatively, you could just use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) too

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  if (!array_key_exists("tags", $v) || $v["tags"] !== "box") {
    continue;
  }

  echo $k, " ", $v["url"], "\n";
}
```

Same output

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(...); // contains your array structure
$matches = array();  // stick the matches in here

foreach ($array as $key => $arr)
{
    if ( ! empty($arr['tags']) && $arr['tags'] === 'box')
    {
        // the array contains tag => box so stick it in the matches array
        $matches[$key] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try something like this to loop your `$array`

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    if(isset($arr['tags']) && $arr['tags'] == "box"){
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```